# jQuery code not firing on page despite registering and enqueuing scripts

Tags: jquery

I want to run this jQuery code I named **service.js** that I put into my theme's js folder:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function(){
jQuery("#tues").click(function(){
    jQuery(".servicecontent").fadeOut(800).hide();
    jQuery(".servicecontent3").fadeOut(800).hide();
    jQuery(".servicecontent2").fadeIn(800).show();
    jQuery(this).fadeIn(800).addClass("active");
    jQuery("#sunday").removeClass("active").addClass("day");
    jQuery("#wed").removeClass("active").addClass("day");
    });
jQuery("#wed").click(function(){
    jQuery(".servicecontent").fadeOut(800).hide();
    jQuery(".servicecontent2").fadeOut(800).hide();
    jQuery(".servicecontent3").fadeIn(800).show();
    jQuery(this).fadeIn(800).addClass("active");
    jQuery("#sunday").removeClass("active").addClass("day");
    jQuery("#tues").removeClass("active").addClass("day");
    });
jQuery("#sunday").click(function(){
    jQuery(".servicecontent2").fadeOut(800).hide();
    jQuery(".servicecontent3").fadeOut(800).hide();
    jQuery(".servicecontent").fadeIn(800).show();
    jQuery(this).fadeIn(800).addClass("active");
    jQuery("#wed").removeClass("active").addClass("day");
    jQuery("#tues").removeClass("active").addClass("day");
    });
})( jQuery );
```

I enqueued it in my functions.php folder as such:

```
$handle = 'NLBBC_styles';
wp_register_style( $handle, get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/NLBBC_styles.css', array(), true );
wp_register_script('service', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/service.js', array( 'jquery' ), true );
 if ( is_page_template( 'page-home.php' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( $handle );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'service' );
}
```

*Ignore the stylesheet lines*

This won't trigger for some reason on the page. What on earth is wrong here?

Maybe I'm missing something but is this correct here?

Do I need to deregister and then register the Google CDN of the jQuery library?

Comment: On what action do you enqueue the scripts?

Comment: This is my first time _trying_ to script in Wordpress. Am I missing the add action command??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) and [`wp_enqueue_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) should be called within a function attached to the [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/) action:

```
// Register scripts and styles. They can be optionally enqueued later on.
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'wpse245419_register_scripts' );
function wpse245419_register_scripts() {
    wp_register_style( 'NLBBC_styles', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/NLBBC_styles.css', array(), true );
    wp_register_script( 'service', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/service.js', array( 'jquery' ), true );
}

// Enqueue scripts and styles.
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse245419_enqueue_scripts' );
function wpse245419_enqueue_scripts() {
    // Only enqueue scripts and styles when the page-home.php template is used.
    if ( is_page_template( 'page-home.php' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'NLBBC_styles');
        wp_enqueue_script( 'service' );
    }
}
```

Comment: But _registration_ should happen on `wp_loaded`.

Comment: Only problem is now the stylesheets are not loading.

Comment: @toscho interesting. Thank you! Updated answer accordingly.

Comment: Hi Ethan, are you viewing the `page-home.php` template? Based on the way this code is set up, `NLBBC_styles` will only be enqueued on that template. If you want `NLBBC_styles` enqueued everywhere, move `wp_enqueue_style( 'NLBBC_styles');` outside of the conditional statement.

Comment: Correct I only need both the styles and the script loading for that template alone. However, it still fails to load the stylesheet as the page is only displaying the HTML. @DaveRomsey

Comment: @toscho - does `wp_loaded` conflict with what is stated on the codex? https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style - "Use the wp_enqueue_scripts action to call this function. Calling it outside of an action can lead to problems. See #17916 for details."

Comment: @jgraup The Codex information is wrong; that's unfortunately often the case. The first registered handle wins, so you *have to* register it early to be sure that you don't get a wrong script/stylesheet with the same handle.

Comment: Can you update the Codex?

Comment: @Ethan For what it's worth, I tested code in my answer using my own stylesheet, JS, and template file and it all works; The stylesheet and JS are loaded when the template passed to `is_page_template()` is being viewed.

Comment: Not sure myself why it won't work because I'm sure the jQuery code is working as I have it up locally. Is the syntax of the jQuery wrong? Do I need to change my noConflict wrap to jQuery( document ).ready(function($){ $("#tues").click...?

Comment: Check the developer console for 404s and JS errors, try removing the `is_page_templage()` conditional. A JS error would show up in the console. I'd use no conflict wrappers, but if that was your issue it would be in the console.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and mark your answer as the accepted answer because it does a great job of explaining the issue. It's probably something with my syntax or what not but I'll progress. Thanks man @DaveRomsey!

Comment: You got it, Ethan. Keep at it! . Verify that the JS is being loaded in developer tools > Network > JS (assuming you're using Chrome). If not, try removing that `is_page_templage()` check. If it is loading, and there are no errors, try replacing you jquery code with a simple `console.log('the js has loaded!');`. Ya know, divide and conquer.